# How to tactfully deal with friend who claims that I am in 'his' team?

Tags: friends, friendship, jealousy

I and one of my friends play a game 'X' and we play equally well. Whenever we have a team (pair) event, both of us pair up. However, in presence of others, he often says that I am in 'his' team. In fact, he once remarked while playing with another team that he chose me in his team because I played very well.

**How can I make my friend understand that such comments make me uncomfortable?**

I feel I shouldn't talk to him about this directly as I don't want to escalate (he is very nice to talk with in general and it isn't a major issue). It's just that I don't want to listen silently and let others take my silence for granted. The next time it happens, I want to prepare myself for a tactful response in order to make him realize that such comments are unwelcome.

Comment: Which part of the comment is making you uncomfortable? Is it just the choice of words?

Comment: In this pair-up situation you are a team, aren't you? So could this wording be not more than a colloquial way of expressing he appreciates you as a good player and likes to play together with you?

Comment: The choice of his words as well as the timing of his comments convince me of his competitive behavior towards me. However, he does so in a smart fashion so that not many take notice of his intentions.

Comment: Is the problem that he calls it “his“ team? Or what exactly is the issue?

Comment: The issue is that he wants to portray to others that he has 'accepted' me as his teammate rather than we decided to play together as equals. I, on the hand, neither like captaining somebody nor being captained by somebody else.

Comment: @Pikachu hey, has he actually said this? (That he has "accepted" you as his teammate) At the end of the day if I remember correctly chess is very objectively measurable and it's pretty easy to tell who's a good player

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum He never said it explicitly (for obvious reasons) but he wants to show that it is he who has chosen me. In fact, I have other choices too but I don't want to strain friendship so that option is ruled out. As far as the measure of better is concerned, we are the same rating level and we have won an equal number of games against each other (of course, we don't count the exact number of wins). Also, I wanted to ask this question for the future too; perhaps in some different context since I am not spontaneous with words.

Comment: Thanks, then I think my answer makes sense. Please consider editing clarifications into the question itself (comments tend to be deleted).

Answer (score 3):

Next time when he says:

> Pickachu is on my team

You can reply *as it happens*:

> *Our team*, we are both on *our* team.

That is non confrontational and objective and should clear things up. There is no need to make this into a bigger issue than it is.

Unless he has explicitly said otherwise it is likely that he does not in fact want to portray that he has "accepted" you and has another reason. For example: people think about things from their own perspective first usually.

Be very careful of [mind reading](https://www.psychologytoday.com/intl/basics/mind-reading).

If you want to bring it up directly (which you absolutely can - it's fine) you can say something like:

> Hey FRIEND, I noticed that uses of "Pikachu is on my team" sometimes. Would you be OK saying "Pikachu and I are on the same team" instead because that would clarify we are partners and friends in the team?

It's entirely possible he has no idea of the subtleties - or he does and calling him on it would make him pay better attention to the issue.

Focus on the facts (what wording was used) and not the subjectives or unknowns (his intentions). Contrast it with positives (we're friends and partners) and emphasize your shared success.

Best of luck with your friends and good luck with your chess :)

Comment: Thanks. It seems a good idea to just say "Our team, we are both on our team." as suggested by you. Especially since it is very less likely to be confrontational.